# Equivalent function with date_create() for php 4

Tags: php

I've no option but to choose PHP4.4.4 in my office. When I created a function using date_create() in PHP5 on my laptop works fine but in my office computer,it leaves an error like below:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: date_create()
Same goes for date_diff() also.

I understand it's due to the version incompatibility issue.
Can anybody suggest other equivalent function for these two to be used in PHP4?
Thanks.

Comment: what are you specifically trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to change user selected date to proper format ,then calculate the difference between two dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `date()` function for this purpose.It works on php 4.It Formats a local time/date.

A sample from the   [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date("l");
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
echo "July 1, 2000 is on a " . date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
echo date(DATE_RFC2822);

echo date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use strtotime ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php ) to convert things to unix timestamps and do your date calculations that way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard date() function. It works on PHP4 and doesn't rely on the DateTime class. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

And to do date math, you can use mktime() with date().
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert your dates to timestamps and do the math, but probably you'll have to take care of Daylight Saving Time and timezones:

```php
$time1 = strtotime("2014-12-23");
$time2 = strtotime("2015-12-23");
$diff = $time2 - $time1;
$diff_in_days = $diff / (60 * 60 * 24);
```